# Simple class won't work in C++

Tags: function, class, tostring

I have a question regarding classes in C++. I just wrote my first class by the help of my book and the exercise goes as follow:

Write a class book with a name, author and publisher. Make an object with hardcoded given text in the main. Let the book show by the use of the ToString() function. Do not leave the constructor empty and make use of the this-> pointer.

I have 0 errors in my compiler but it shows nothing and ends immediatly (my program), can somebody explain what I've done wrong and why the compiler hasn't seen my mistake?
I also have tried making an object on the heap but also won't work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class Book
{
private:
string name;
string author;
string publisher;

public:
Book(string name, string author, string publisher)
{
    this->name=name;
    this->author=author;
    this->publisher=publisher;
}

~Book(void)
{
}

string getName();
string getAuthor();
string getPublisher();
void setName(string name);
void setAuthor(string author);
void setPublisher(string publisher);
string toString();
};


string Book::getName()
{
return name;
}

string Book::getAuthor()
{
return author;
}

string Book::getPublisher()
{
return publisher;
}

void Book::setName(string name)
{
this->name=name;
}

void Book::setAuthor(string author)
{
this->author=author;
}

void Book::setPublisher(string publisher)
{
this->publisher=publisher;
}

string Book::toString()
{
stringstream ss;
ss << "Name of the book: " << name << endl;
ss << "Author of the book: " << author << endl;
ss << "The book has been published by: " << publisher << endl;
return ss.str();
}


int main()
{
Book b1=Book("The lone child","Bryan Addams", "Publishers INC");
b1.toString();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: In tubro c++ use getCh() to see your results. And in Dev C++ use System("pause")

Comment: Put either of these before return 0; statement

Comment: It's not showing anything because you're not telling it to. You have to output the return value of `Book::toString()` somehow (cf. operator<< for std::cout).

Comment: @Nabin He can pause the screen for 20 years, it's still not going to produce output if there's no code in the program that actually produces output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are never actually printing the return value of `b1.toString()`, so of course there is no output.  Capturing the return value of `toString();` and then printing it works.

```
int main () {
  Book b1 = Book( "The lone child", "Bryan Addams", "Publishers INC");

  string s = b1.toString();

  cout << s << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Or just printing it directly, as in:

```
int main () {
  Book b1 = Book( "The lone child", "Bryan Addams", "Publishers INC");

  cout << b1.toString() << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't knew you had to also cout << the b1.tostring(); ! thank you !!!

Comment: Your `toString()` method uses the `<<` operator to serialize your object to a string representation by employing the `std::stringstream` class.  This is a serialization method, and produces no IO output.  It's easy to make the mistake because `<<` looks like what you're accustomed to seeing with `std::cout`.  But think of it as a "feed this to that" operator.  In the case of `cout`, you're feeding something to an output stream.  In the case of `stringstream`, you're feeding something to a stream that produces a string, and that's all.

Answer (score 2):

You program works fine. You just dont print anything. You call

```
 b1.toString();
```

Which only returns a string. Try replacing it with

```
cout << b1.toString();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It was easier than i tought!

Answer (score -1):

Instead of returning `ss.str` in the string `toString()` function,
You should print it there.

```
string Book:toString(){
    ...
    cout << ss.str;
    ...
}
```

Comment: But then the method `toString()` would do something different from serializing to a string, it would be printing, and should probably be named `print()` instead.  And if you want toString() to print, its return type should probably not be a `std::string`.